# console-kit-daemon : GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

Tags: message, daemon, linux-mint

When I run Linuxmint 18.1, I get this error. Which error can be associated with this message? And how I can solve this?

I searched for answers and I [found this](https://appbead.com/blog/fix-errors-reported-in-syslog-for-debian-8-jessie.html), but I don't understand it very well. Can any one explain the problem a bit better, please?

Comment: Looking for the error from there I read that arises because console-kit-daemon is trying to login in graphical mode, when I am really in console mode. Is that why the error occurs? Should i delete it?